# Why can't MySQL refer to a temporary table twice?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

The [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/temporary-table-problems.html) state:

> You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query.

as a "known limitation". However, I'm curious *why* MySQL has this quirk. Unfortunately, most answers to questions about it stop at "the docs say...".

Could somebody with insight into how MySQL works provide context for this (IMO) bug?

- Were there historical decisions that force this limitation?
- Are there interesting complications that make changing it impossible?
- Will it stick around forever because there are simple work arounds?

I'm hoping that I'll learn something interesting about MySQL, and maybe get insight into what motivates development.

Comment: This limitation is lifted in [MariaDB 10.2.1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-1021-release-notes/) "Temporary tables can be referred to many times in the same query ([MDEV-5535](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-5535))". There is also an [explanation](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-5535?focusedCommentId=68989&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-68989) from Sergei Golubchik, why it didn't work.